# Oracle SQL query to see if characters are in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query if the characters 'th' is in a column enames for the table emp.

I use the command

```
select ename from emp where ename like '%th';
```

However SQL says no row selected.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

SOLVED

This worked in the end.

```
 SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ENAME LIKE '%TH%';
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You are trying to find th or 'th' (value containing single quotes at both end)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where ename like '%t%' or ename like '%h%';
```

or with a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(ename, '[th]');
```

Comment: when i put the query `select ename from emp where ename like '%t%' or ename like '%h%'` i still get `no row selected` outputed

Comment: Are you sure there are rows with `t` or `h` in the ename?

Comment: in the ename column there are enames which have characters 'th' in them for example a row is 'SMITH' this has 'th'. I wanted to  return all the enames with the characters 'th' in them.

Comment: 'SMITH' does not have 'th'. It has 'TH'.

Comment: yeah thanks, i noticed before i saw your comment i put it in my edit. I will now accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
where UPPER(ename) like '%TH%';
```